# Set TotalCount in ShieldUI Grid for Paging

Tags: gridview, grid, shieldui

I have mapped between action parameters and the `grid` parameters successfully.Now issue is that in database I have 30000 records and when `grid` is loaded because of skip and take parameter it fetch only between this records(e.g between 0 to 10 from database) in that case my page size remains 1. It shows paging depending on number of records in databse. So, please, let me know how can I set paging.

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the schema.total property? It needs to be set, so that the Grid knows how many total number of records are there, and initialize the pager.

Example can be found here:
http://demos.shieldui.com/web/grid-databinding/remote-data